# How to handle the null values for Datetime in c#

Tags: c#

How can I check Start is blank or empty:

```
Employee.CurrentLongTermIncentive.StartDate
```

I have tried the below things:

```
Employee.CurrentLongTermIncentive.StartDate!=null // Start is empty it's falied.

Employee.CurrentLongTermIncentive.StartDate.HasValue // Start is empty it's falied.
```

how can I check the null or blank value for Start date and assign to the string value.
Startdate is having the datetime format.

Comment: How does it fail then? With what error? In what scenarios?

Comment: StartDate is `DateTime` or `DateTime?` or `Nullable<DateTime>` or ?

Comment: Please show us the definition of `StartDate`.

Comment: private DateTime? startdate;
  /// <summary>
  /// Gets or sets .
  /// </summary>
  /// <value>StartDate</value> 
  public virtual DateTime? StartDate
  {
   get { return this.startdate; }
   set 
   { 
    if (this.startdate != value)
    {
     NotifyPropertyChanging("StartDate");
     this.startdate = value; 
     NotifyPropertyChanged("StartDate");
    }
   }
  }

Comment: A `Nullable<DateTime>` cannot be _empty_. It can be undefined. A string can be empty.

Answer (score 4):

An object of type `DateTime` cannot be set to null.  That is the reason why your code may be failing.

You can try using `DateTime.MinValue` to identify instances where a value has not been assigned.

```
Employee.CurrentLongTermIncentive.StartDate != DateTime.MinValue;
```

You can however configure `DateTime` to be nullable using the following Declaration.

```
DateTime? mydate = null;

if (mydate == null) Console.WriteLine("Is Null");
if (mydate.HasValue) Console.WriteLine("Not Null");
```

Note : the `?` - this allows a non-nullable value to assigned as null.

**You seem to be using `DateTime?` for start time, so try the following**

```
if (!Employee.CurrentLongTermIncentive.StartDate.HasValue) {
  Employee.CurrentLongTermIncentive.StartDate = (DateTime?) DateTime.Parse(myDateString);
}
```

where `myDateString` is a string representing the date you want to assign.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want `if Employee.CurrentLongTermIncentive.StartDate != DateTime.MinValue`

Comment: There is no entry present for the Start date in LongTermIncentive table for that Employee and I want to check for the empty start date.The code will fail on .StartDate nullreference exception.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to display it in a textbox just do something like this, just make sure both Employee and CurrentLongTermIncentive are not null:

```
txtStartDate.Text = GetStartDate(Employee.CurrentLongTermIncentive.StartDate);
private string GetStartDate(DateTime? startDate)
{
        if (startDate != null)
        {
            return startDate.Value.ToShortDateString();
        }
        return "";
}
```

Comment: There is no entry present for the Start date in LongTermIncentive table for that Employee and I want to check for the empty start date.